# how to clear a textbox in Python after button is pressed?

Tags: python, customtkinter

I'm starting in python and I have created this app to open a website after you write it in a textbox, but don't know how to clear it after the button is pressed, please help me...

Code:

```py
import customtkinter

import webbrowser

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("system")

customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.geometry("500x350")

def login():

       url = entry1.get()

       webbrowser.open(url)

frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=root)
frame.pack(pady=20, padx=20, fill="both", expand="True")

label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame, text="enter website")
label.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

entry1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame, placeholder_text="website")
entry1.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame, text="Enviar", command=login)
button.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not using `textvariable` property you can use `delete()` method of the widget:

```py
entry1.delete(0, len(entry1.get()))
```

Find the documentation [here](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/entry.html#entry-index) or [here](https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/documentation/widgets/entry)